# Real-time chatting and notifications in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need to implement real-time chatting and real-time notifications in my application. What is the best way to do it using laravel-5? Suggest me some good packages or your expert views on them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For real time chat you need to use asynchronous websockets.

You can try with this library https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet

[laravel 5.2 chat](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-real-time-chat-application-with-modulus-and-laravel-5--cms-24284)

and this project
[github.com/assertchris/tutorial-laravel-4-real-time-chat](http://github.com/assertchris/tutorial-laravel-4-real-time-chat)

Good library
[github.com/BrainBoxLabs/brain-socket](http://github.com/BrainBoxLabs/brain-socket)

also amazing tutorial with socket IO
[www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-and-socket-io-tutorial/](http://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-and-socket-io-tutorial/)

Video example with AJAX and laravel 4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLDjgbbBvOg

Comment: can you use laravel's queue system along with this ? just wondering

Answer (score 19):

I recently gave a talk at Symfony Live on ["Building Real-Time Symfony Apps. What are your options?"](http://leggetter.github.io/realtime-symfony/). As part of that I covered your options for integrating with real-time frameworks. Although the talk is about Symfony it does also apply to Laravel, or any other PHP Framework.

If you want to go self hosted then [Adnan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29882802/39904) covers a number of good options. With PHP, Ratchet-based solutions are your best bet. However it doesn't offer HTTP fallback so you'll need to implement your own fallback mechanism.

[image: PHP + Real-time framework integration]

*Note: substitute Symfony for Laravel in the above image*

Since you're integrating with the real-time framework in a loosely coupled way you're not restricted to a PHP-based solution. In that case there are a number of considerations you need to make before choosing what that solution is (again, please see the [talk](http://leggetter.github.io/realtime-symfony/) I referenced earlier).

You alternative to self-hosted is of course using a hosted service. Laravel 5.1 comes with an [Event Broadcaster](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#broadcasting-events) for the [Pusher](https://pusher.com) hosted real-time service (*who I work for*).

[image: Symfony/Laravel + Pusher]

Taylor Otwell published a video on Laracasts covering how to go about doing this:
https://laracasts.com/lessons/broadcasting-events-in-laravel-5-1

I've also created a set of [tutorials on building real-time laravel apps](https://pusher-community.github.io/real-time-laravel/) that walks you through building a notifications feature, activity streams and then authenticating a chat application.

Comment: I love your diagram. How would rethinkdb fit into this? Would it be a possible substitute for pusher?

Comment: @KimStacks RethinkDB would be a substitute for the database, but not a substitute for the server -> client delivery mechanism.

Comment: Even though rethinkdb has a change feed ?

Comment: @KimStacks - yeah, changefeeds inform your server code when data has changed, but hey don't deliver that data over the wire to connected web or mobile clients.