# Is it possible to create a web chat application in plain Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, web-chat

I just started studying and learning about `Laravel` Framework. My programming originated from Java Desktop application programming and I have not tried any `web framework` in the past. 
I've little knowledge with Javascript, some `PHP, HTML and CSS`.

I would like to know if it's possible and advisable to create a chat application within a social network website I'm planning to create for school semester using Laravel.

If it's not possible, what web programming language for a total web newbie like me can use?

I thought it would be best for me play around and learn Javascript because the coding style is a bit similar to Java.

I would like to create something similar with facebook's chat application.

I'd appreciate any suggestion and help.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Real-time chatting and notifications in laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874943/real-time-chatting-and-notifications-in-laravel-5)

Comment: [It's more than a bit similar](https://gist.github.com/forairan/b1143f42883b3b0ee1237bc9bd0b7b2c) :-) Joking aside, [check this out](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/hoawebsocket-with-laravel-5-projects-push-notifications?page=1) - you need websockets

Comment: @YuriTkachenko Thanks.

Comment: @RobM. Thanks for the link you provided.

Answer (score 1):

For such application you can use [socket.io](http://socket.io/), based on node.js. The website offers a full tutorial to build a webchat.

You could do that in PHP using websockets, but it would be more complicated.

My advice is to keep Laravel for the non-interactive parts of your application and use node.js where you need real-time features.

Answer (score 1):

It's more than possible.
Actually with the new 5.3 release, Laravel provides realtime app from scratch: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting

You need a third party service like pusher, but it's pretty easy to implement.

Go ahead and to dive in into the laravel worl, i can recommand https://laracasts.com/

Have fun! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to ask though, are there libraries or packages in Laravel 5.3 available to manage social network website like what I'm planning to create?

Comment: it's up to you how do you will build it. there are a lot of packages available. but i never done something like that so i can not recommand one.