# real time notification in laravel5.4

Tags: notifications, laravel-5.4

I am working on laravel notification. Can anyone suggest me how to do the real time notification?

I already go through browser. I didn't found any where correct answer.

Can anyone suggest me how to do that? Or has Laravel have any built function?

I am new to Laravel, so this is my first project I am doing in Laravel. So I am not that much of familiar using Laravel. I tried a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Real-time chatting and notifications in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874943/real-time-chatting-and-notifications-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 1):

You have three options. Either Ajax, WebSocket or Realtime technologies.

In ajax, you need to use `setInterval()` to check every second.

```
setInvertal(function(){
   fetch_notifications();
}, 1000);
```

In websocket. It's free but it requires nodejs. Check this. It's laravel 4 but you can easily update to laravel 5. http://www.volkomenjuist.nl/blog/2013/10/20/laravel-4-and-nodejsredis-pubsub-realtime-notifications/

Lastly, using realtime web technologies. Most of them are giving free, it up to you if you want to upgrade your account. Check this lists.
https://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide/
Laravel recommends using pusher, its good. For my self, I would recommend using PubNub. It's very popular and easy to use. Check this. https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2011-03-19-build-real-time-chat-10-lines-code/

Ably is good too.

Goodluck.

Answer (score 1):

Your post is duplicated...

"Laravel Echo", i think it's what you want for real time notification.

https://laracasts.com/lessons/introducing-laravel-echo

look at this post : [Real-time chatting and notifications in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874943/real-time-chatting-and-notifications-in-laravel-5)